# how to run an image of software on other node?

Tags: docker

hello I've installed a docker on my local machine in which in container I've installed image file of arangodb on my local machine so my question is that how to fetch an image of arangodb on other PC without downloading again on other PC? what I've to use docker-compose or docker-swarm ?please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker save` to save that docker image to a .tar file. The syntax is like this:

`docker save -o output_file_name.tar image_name:image_tag`

Then, you have to copy that .tar file to the other computer and load it using `docker load`. The syntax is like this:

`docker load -i output_file_name.tar`

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: here if once the image loaded we need to download the image again? if not then how can we run?

Comment: After load it you have to execute `docker run...`